# Is it possible appending remote files into local tar file using python's tarfile module?

Tags: python, ssh, tar, tarfile

I'm trying to create local tar file out of remote files,

I have managed doing that in command line with following two commands:

run the following command for each full_path_to_input_file that I want to add:

```
ssh <remote_computer_name> 'tar uvf <full_path_to_tar.tar> <full_path_to_input_file>'
```

and after that run (to compress the file):

```
gzip <full_path_to_input_file>
```

So, I think I can solve the problem using os.system("...") python command with the above two commands, But I want to know if maybe python's **tarfile** module supports that?
to avoid executing external commands in a shell.

I have seen that **tarfile** module has the add method:
***TarFile.add(name, arcname=None, recursive=True, *, filter=None)*** but it seems that name can't be remote, am I right?
if not, I would really appreciate some code snippet showing how to use that method on remote files.

The background is this:
I have a system, build of multiple computers (the exact number varies from system to system), each of which is generating all kinds of log files.
On some erroneous states I need to collect all logs from all computers of the system (suppose: master, slave-1, slave-2, etc.).
Until now, the code used to ***rsync*** the remote files to some local dir, and after collecting all the log files **tarfile.add** was used on this directory to create tar file.
This solution is problematic since there could be a situation that HD of master (the local computer) is nearly full, no place to both copy all the logs on it and create tar file, So I need the create the tar file "on the fly" - appending each remote file to the local tar.

So, if **TarFile.add** can't support this requirements,
maybe you can suggest me some other solution?
By the way, I'm using Python 2.7 and tarfile version is 0.9.0.

Thank you so much in advance! :)

Comment: You want to read the `addfile` mehod's description instead, and probably present the remote file as a `BytesIO` object you can wrap with `gettarinfo` as the documentation explains.

Comment: Writing new code in Python 2 seems like a very dubious idea. Are you really sure you don't want to target Python 3 instead, or at least use `six` or similar to avoid targeting _only_ the old unsupported version?

Comment: using `ssh`  you don't run `tar` installed on your computer but `tar` installed on remote computer. If you copy your Python script on remote computer and it has installed Python then you can run your script with `tarfile` by `ssh`.

Comment: @tripleee, I have read the documentation of addfile & BytesIO, but couldn't understand how to use them to get the desired result. Can you maybe give me some code example from which I can learn?
Regarding choosing python 2 instead of 3, It really not depends on me, it's what installed at the moment on client's machines and I can't change it be my self, but I agree, it's  a step that the company I work in should do. Regarding "six", I'm not familiar with it, will try reading about it later.

furas I couldn't manage to get to the bottom of what you were trying to say, can you kindly elaborate?

Comment: They are saying `ssh tar` does something rather different than what you are asking about here. There is no simple built-in way to read a "remote file" over SSH so you would need to use something like Paramiko which provides this abstraction. I'm afraid I'm not in a place where I can provide actual working code for this right now.